# Database design, an included attribute vs multiple joins? Confused

Tags: database, rdbms

So I am taking a class in database design and management and am kind of confused from a design perspective.  My example is an invoice system.  I just made it up quick so it doesn't have a ton of complexity in it.

There are Customers, Orders, Invoices and Payments entities

**Customers** 
CustId(PK),
Street,
Zip,
City,
..

**Orders**
OrderID(PK)
CustID(FK)
Date
Amt
....

**Invoices**
InvoiceID(PK),
OrderID(FK),
Date,
AmtDue,
AmtPaid,
....

**Payments**
PaymentNo(PK),
InvoiceID(FK),
PayMethod,
Date,
Amt,
...

Customer entity has a one to many relationship with Orders

Purchases entity has a one to many relationship with Invoices

Invoices Entity has a one to many relationship with Payments.

To get the results of a query to list all Payments made by a Customer the query would have to join Payments with the Invoice table, the Invoice table with the Orders table and the Orders table with the Customer table.

Is this the correct way to do it?  One could also just put a custID in the payment entity which would then just require one join, but then there is unneeded information in the payment entity.  Is this just a design thing or is it a performance issue?

Bonus question.  Lets say there should be a report that says what the total customer balance is.  Does there need to be a customer balance field in the database or can this be a calculated item that is produced by joining tables and adding up the amount billed vs amount paid?

Thanks!

Comment: Constraints (PKs, FKs, cardinalities, etc) are not needed to query. What a row means when in a table (base or query result) is necessary & sufficient. Also, time to read a textbook re introduction to information modeling & relational databases.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct way to do it?

Yes.  Based on the information provided, it looks reasonable.

> One could also just put a custID in the payment entity which would then just require one join, but then there is unneeded information in the payment entity. Is this just a design thing or is it a performance issue?

The question you're asking falls under "normal forms", often called normalization.  Your target should be Boyce-Codd normal form (similar to 3NF), which should be described in your textbook.  I will warn you that misinformation and misuderstanding of database design issues is very abundant on the interwebs, so beware of which answers you pay attention to.

The goal of normalization is to eliminate redundancy, and thus to eliminate "anomaliies", whereby two logically equivalent queries produce inconsistent results.  If the same information is kept in two places, and is updated in only one, then two queries against the two different values will produce different -- i.e, inconsistent -- results.

In your example, if there is a Payments.CustID, should I believe that one, or the one derived from joining Payments to Orders?  The same goes for total customer balance: do I believe the stored total, or the one I computed from the consituents?

If you are going to "denomalize for performance", as is so often alleged to be necessary, what are you going to do to ensure the redundant values are consistent?

> Bonus question. Lets say there should be a report that says what the total customer balance is.

As a matter of fact, in practice balances are sort of a special case.  It's often necessary to know the balance at points in time.  While it's possible to compute, say, monthy account balances from inception based on transactions, *as a practical matter* applications usually "draw a line in the sand" and record the balance for future reference.  Step *are* taken -- must be, for the sake of the business -- to ensure the historical information does not change or, if it does, that the recorded balance is updated to reflect the change.  From that description alone, you can imagine that the work of enforcing consistency throughout the system is *much* more work than relying on the DBMS to enforce it.  And that is why, insofar as is feasible, it's better to elimate all redundant data, and let the DBMS do the job it was designed to do.

In your analysis, seek Boyce-Codd normal form.  Understand your data, eliminate the redundancies, and recognize the relations.  Let the DBMS enforce referential integrity.  Countless errors will be avoided, and time saved.  Only when specific circumstances conspire to show that specific business requirements cannot be satisfied on a particular system with a given, correct design, does one begin the tedious and error-prone work of introducing redundant information and compensating for it with external controls.

Comment: Thank you for the answer/comment.  I will read it over a few times and dive deeper into my book(it is really poorly written unfortunately).  One follow up question on the balance issue.  Since a lot of the balance COULD be done with math outside of a stored entity it sounds like the need for a balance is more a historical nature.  In the real world would this look like having an entity like 'AccountBlanceHisotry' which is updated via trigger anytime a payment or interest accrual is applied?

Comment: There is a temptation to use triggers to keep a summary table like historical balances up to date.  I don't advise it.  Triggers can be bypassed, and need to be bidirectional to ensure consistency in both directions (no matter which table is updated).  Better to restrict the use of triggers to enforce referential integrity only (existence tests).  Instead, use stored procedures to update both tables in a transaction, and deny insert/update/delete permissions on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

"Is this the correct way to do it?" Of course, given your current design. But it's not the ONLY way. So you're studying DB "normalization" and seeing the pros and cons of the various "forms" of normalization. In the "real world" things can change on a dime, due to a management decision or whatever. I tend to use "compound primary keys" instead of simply one field for primary and others as FK. I handle my "FK" programmatically instead of relegating that responsibility to the DB.
I also create and utilize a number of "intermediate" tables, or sometimes "VIEWS", that I use more easily than a bunch of code with too many JOINs. (3rd Normal form addicts can hate, but my code runs faster than a scalded rabbit).
An Order means nothing without a Customer; an Invoice means nothing without an Order; a Payment is great, but means nothing without both an Order and Invoice. So lemme throw this out there -- what's wrong with having a "summary" type of entity that has Cust, Order, Invoice #, and Payment Id ?

Comment: Wouldn't having a 'Summary' type of entity as you suggest have a lot of repetitive information?

Comment: The "summary" entity would just *beg* to have other information added to it, such as totals, addresses, payment info, etc, etc, etc. It's an attractive nuisance which results in data duplication/inconsistency.

Comment: If you think an order is meaningless without a customer, you've never been a manager demanding a trend report on total orders.  OTOH, if the customer for an order is important, why on earth not "relegate" referential integrity enforcement to the DBMS, which can protect that consistency uniformly against all application/administrative errors?

Comment: That is my confusion I guess.  What needs to be stored and what can be calculated?  For example, lets say its a company that bills large values and depending on the payment terms charges interest on a total balance, almost like a loan.  Would you need to have a 'Principle Amount', 'Interest Amount' etc etc attribute or would you just need the original invoice amounts of each invoice and the total amount paid split between interest and principle?  When you want to figure out the total balance you would query and do the math outside of an entity attribute?

Comment: @James K. Lowden, I've been a mgr reporting on orders. Our system wouldn't have an order with no customer. Why don't I relegate RI enforcement to an online system? That goes back to my IBM days when we designed a 3N system & then crashed a client's mainframe partition because of strict adherence to 3rd normal form.There were too many "JOINs" necessary,& we all learned something from that .We learned the business concept of "primary tables" & "secondary tables" or "views" -- whatever your business rules may accommodate. We may do such things in "batch" -- we NEVER do it "online".

Comment: If you are having a problem with having a "summary table" that simply lists Customers, Orders, Invoices, and Payments, then I don't know what else to suggest. If you want to design the perfect 3rd Normal form system, then by all means go for it, brutha. Let us know how you will deal with the real-world consequences of that approach in the future -- I'd love to know. You can listen to the "philosophy of the moment" or you can do your best research to get your code to work efficiently and effectively. Ask your management which approach you should take.

Comment: @McAuley, I don't doubt your negative experience.  When DRI first became available in the 90s, it was impractical on the software and hardware of the day.  It's a mistake to extrapolate that experience to all systems for all time.  The performance of any system is idiosyncratic.  Often, tuning can change performance by orders of magnitude.  Defeating the DBMS's built-in features is not always the solution.